# How to load a project developed in 32 bit machine in 64 bit?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing winforms application in visual studio 2012. I have a desktop pc 32 bit and windows 7 os. I installed Visual studio 2012 and developed a winform application in .net framework 4.5 (vb.net). Now I need to load the same project in my laptop that is 64 bit with windows 8. I installed same visual studio 2012 version and tried to load the project. I got the following warnings. How to solve them and to load the project successfully?

[image]

Comment: You are using ancient VB6 controls.  Of course you don't have them installed on your nice new laptop, you wouldn't consider abusing it like that :)  Time to move ahead and get rid of them.

Comment: So now what exactly i have to install?

Comment: That the VB6 hint wasn't enough is a problem.  You'll need to talk to the original programmer, you also need to dig up the custom controls like "ComCtl3".  If this project has an installer to get it on the user's machine then you ought to consider running it.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the assembly targets the x86 processor architecture within the project properties.  Go to the project properties (right-click on the project in the solution explorer, or hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>)  > "Compile" tab > "Advanced Compile Options" button > "Target CPU" option and select "x86" from the drop-down.

Comment: I went to project properties and selected compile tab and set target cpu from Any cpu to x86 then i build the project, same warnings I'm getting.

Comment: Clean and rebuild your solution?

Comment: Yes i did, still same warnings.